# Stargazer: How to produce frequency/summary tables for string variables

Tags: r, stargazer

**Heres what Id like to achieve:**

Id like to produce frequency tables with stargazer of string variables from a questionnaire.

One variable is gender (which is labelled "female" here, and has the values "male" and "female" here). Another example would be the variable "whyjob" (asking participants why they chose their job, with the values "only option", "tradition" and "best option"). 
I need those tables in latex and to additionally report the number of observations in that category. Thats why I chose stargazer, because it can do both.

**The trouble I ran into:**

*Code:*

`df.female<-as.data.frame(D[["female"]]) # convert to data frame because o.w. I have the error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
stargazer(df.female, type="text")`

*Output:*

This is what the output looked like. Empty.

```
===================================================
Statistic N Mean St. Dev. Min Pctl(25) Pctl(75) Max
===================================================
```

**What I already tried:**

1.
I thought that if i eliminated the statistics that obviously weren't applicable for a variable such as gender(mean,sd....), and only displayed the ones that would work (median), it'd help, but the table still turns up empty.
Code: `stargazer(df.female, type="text",summary.logical=T, summary.stat="median",iqr=F, omit.summary.stat = c("p25","p75","mean","sd","max"))`

2.
Also, when I simply tried to make a table for all variables together, the result only displayed numerical variables and omitted the others.

3.
Another idea - which I haven't tried yet- is to simply turn gender into a dummy. That doesn't solve my general problem with the other variables, though, so the question remains.

**Hence, my question is:**

- How can I display those frequency tables for dummy/string/categorial variables?
- If stargazer doesn't deliver that; is there another package that both produces latex tables and can report the number of observations?